# trouble with wordpress save_post when saving data

Tags: php, wordpress

i'm trying to accomplish a simple stars voting system in wordpress, though i want to add it to the defaul post post_type. This code works perfectly in a custom post type but for some reason when i add it to default post and try to update the post or publish, it trwos me to a blank screen, if i go back to previous page, the data is saved. Here is the code i have, hope you can help me.

```html
// Agregar metabox Para votaciones de critica

add_action( 'add_meta_boxes_post', 'votacion_critica_metabox' );
function votacion_critica_metabox()
{
 add_meta_box( 'metabox-critica-votacion', 'Votacion para Criticas', 'votacion_critica_metabox_callback', 'post', 'normal', 'high' );
}

function votacion_critica_metabox_callback( $post )
 
{
 $post_id = $post->ID;
 $values = get_post_meta( $post->ID );
 $rating5 = get_post_meta( $post->ID,'rating5', true );
 $rating4 = get_post_meta( $post->ID,'rating4', true );
 $rating3 = get_post_meta( $post->ID,'rating3', true );
 $rating2 = get_post_meta( $post->ID,'rating2', true );
 $rating1 = get_post_meta( $post->ID,'rating1', true );
 $votaciones = $rating1 + $rating2 + $rating3 + $rating4 + $rating5;
 $dividendo = (1 * $rating1) + (2 * $rating2) + (3 * $rating3) + (4 * $rating4) + (5 * $rating5);
 $promedio = $dividendo/$votaciones;
 $votantes1 = get_post_meta( $post->ID,'votantes', true );
 
    wp_nonce_field( 'critica_nonce', 'mi_critica_nonce' );
    ?>
  <br><input type="hidden" name="votantes" id="my_meta_box_prueba" size="30" placeholder="votantes" value="<?php echo $votantes1; ?>" />
  
  </br>
  <input type="hidden" id="promedio" name="promedio" value="1" />
  <div class="rating">
  <div class="cover" ></div>
  <input type="radio" id="star5" name="resultado5"  <?php if ( $promedio == 5 ) {echo 'checked';} ?> /><label for="star5" title="Muy bueno">5 stars</label>
  
  <input type="radio" id="star4" name="resultado4"  <?php if ( $promedio >= 4 && $promedio < 5 ) {echo 'checked';} ?> /><label for="star4" title="Bueno">4 stars</label>
  
  <input type="radio" id="star3" name="resultado3"  <?php if ( $promedio >= 3 && $promedio < 4 ) {echo 'checked';} ?> /><label for="star3" title="Regular">3 stars</label>
  
  <input type="radio" id="star2" name="resultado2"  <?php if ( $promedio >= 2 && $promedio < 3 ) {echo 'checked';} ?> /><label for="star2" title="Malo">2 stars</label>
  
  <input type="radio" id="star1" name="resultado1"  <?php if ( $promedio >= 1 && $promedio < 2 ) {echo 'checked';} ?> /><label for="star1" title="Muy Malo">1 star</label>
  
  </br>
        <?php 
  if ( is_user_logged_in() ) { $user = get_current_user_id(); }
  $votantes = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'votantes', false); if (in_array($user, $votantes)) {} else {echo 
  '<input type="radio" id="star5" name="rating5" value="' .$rating5. '" /><label for="star5" title="Muy Bueno">5 stars</label>
   <input type="radio" id="star4" name="rating4" value="' .$rating4. '" /><label for="star4" title="Bueno">4 stars</label>
   <input type="radio" id="star3" name="rating3" value="' .$rating3. '" /><label for="star3" title="Regular">3 stars</label>
   <input type="radio" id="star2" name="rating2" value="' .$rating2. '" /><label for="star2" title="Malo">2 stars</label>
   <input type="radio" id="star1" name="rating1" value="' .$rating1. '" /><label for="star1" title="Muy Malo">1 star</label>';} ?>  
  </div>
  </br>
  </br>
  Número de Votaciones: <?php echo $votaciones; ?>
  </br>
  <?php  if ($votantes1 == "") {echo 'null';} else {echo $votantes1;} ?>
  </br>
  <?php  echo $user; ?>
  </br>
  <?php  if (in_array($user, $votantes)) { echo 'el usuario si está'; } else {echo 'el usuario no está';}  ?>
  
  <p>Promedio de Puntuación: <?php echo $promedio; ?></p>
  <p>Dividendo: <?php echo $dividendo; ?></p>
  
    </div>
     <?php
}

$votantes = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'votantes', false);  
  
add_action( 'save_post', 'votacion_critica_metabox_save' );
function votacion_critica_metabox_save( $post_id )
{
    // Bail if we're doing an auto save
    if( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) return;

    // if Nonce isn't there, or we can't verify it, bail
    if( !isset( $_POST['mi_critica_nonce'] ) || !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['mi_critica_nonce'], 'critica_nonce' ) ) return;

    // if Current user can't edit this post, bail
    if( !current_user_can( 'edit_post' ) ) return;

    // Save the data
 
    // Review data before saving
  if ( is_user_logged_in() ) { echo $user = get_current_user_id(); }
 if (isset( $_POST['rating5'] ) OR isset( $_POST['rating4'] ) OR isset( $_POST['rating3'] ) OR isset( $_POST['rating2'] ) OR isset( $_POST['rating1'] )) {add_post_meta( $post_id, 'votantes', $user);}
 if( empty( $_POST['rating5'] )) {add_post_meta( $post_id, 'rating5', 0, true );} 
 if (isset( $_POST['rating5'] )) {update_post_meta( $post_id, 'rating5', $rating5 = $_POST['rating5'] + 1 );}
 if( empty( $_POST['rating4'] )) {add_post_meta( $post_id, 'rating4', 0, true );} 
 if (isset( $_POST['rating4'] )) {update_post_meta( $post_id, 'rating4', $rating4 = $_POST['rating4'] + 1 );}
 if( empty( $_POST['rating3'] )) {add_post_meta( $post_id, 'rating3', 0, true );} 
 if (isset( $_POST['rating3'] )) {update_post_meta( $post_id, 'rating3', $rating3 = $_POST['rating3'] + 1 );}
 if( empty( $_POST['rating2'] )) {add_post_meta( $post_id, 'rating2', 0, true );} 
 if (isset( $_POST['rating2'] )) {update_post_meta( $post_id, 'rating2', $rating2 = $_POST['rating2'] + 1 );}
 if( empty( $_POST['rating1'] )) {add_post_meta( $post_id, 'rating1', 0, true );} 
 if (isset( $_POST['rating1'] )) {update_post_meta( $post_id, 'rating1', $rating1 = $_POST['rating1'] + 1 );}
 
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved this issue, was printing the user_id in the save_post function and didn't notice.

```html
right here after the save_post add action

// Review data before saving
  if ( is_user_logged_in() ) { echo $user = get_current_user_id(); }
  
changed to:

 // Review data before saving
  if ( is_user_logged_in() ) { $user = get_current_user_id(); }
```

```html
// Agregar metabox Para votaciones de critica

add_action( 'add_meta_boxes_post', 'votacion_critica_metabox' );
function votacion_critica_metabox()
{
 add_meta_box( 'metabox-critica-votacion', 'Votacion para Criticas', 'votacion_critica_metabox_callback', 'post', 'normal', 'high' );
}

function votacion_critica_metabox_callback( $post )
 
{
 $post_id = $post->ID;
 $values = get_post_meta( $post->ID );
 $rating5 = get_post_meta( $post->ID,'rating5', true );
 $rating4 = get_post_meta( $post->ID,'rating4', true );
 $rating3 = get_post_meta( $post->ID,'rating3', true );
 $rating2 = get_post_meta( $post->ID,'rating2', true );
 $rating1 = get_post_meta( $post->ID,'rating1', true );
 $votaciones = $rating1 + $rating2 + $rating3 + $rating4 + $rating5;
 $dividendo = (1 * $rating1) + (2 * $rating2) + (3 * $rating3) + (4 * $rating4) + (5 * $rating5);
 $promedio = $dividendo/$votaciones;
 $votantes1 = get_post_meta( $post->ID,'votantes', true );
 
    wp_nonce_field( 'critica_nonce', 'mi_critica_nonce' );
    ?>
  <br><input type="hidden" name="votantes" id="my_meta_box_prueba" size="30" placeholder="votantes" value="<?php echo $votantes1; ?>" />
  
  </br>
  <input type="hidden" id="promedio" name="promedio" value="1" />
  <div class="rating">
  <div class="cover" ></div>
  <input type="radio" id="star5" name="resultado5"  <?php if ( $promedio == 5 ) {echo 'checked';} ?> /><label for="star5" title="Muy bueno">5 stars</label>
  
  <input type="radio" id="star4" name="resultado4"  <?php if ( $promedio >= 4 && $promedio < 5 ) {echo 'checked';} ?> /><label for="star4" title="Bueno">4 stars</label>
  
  <input type="radio" id="star3" name="resultado3"  <?php if ( $promedio >= 3 && $promedio < 4 ) {echo 'checked';} ?> /><label for="star3" title="Regular">3 stars</label>
  
  <input type="radio" id="star2" name="resultado2"  <?php if ( $promedio >= 2 && $promedio < 3 ) {echo 'checked';} ?> /><label for="star2" title="Malo">2 stars</label>
  
  <input type="radio" id="star1" name="resultado1"  <?php if ( $promedio >= 1 && $promedio < 2 ) {echo 'checked';} ?> /><label for="star1" title="Muy Malo">1 star</label>
  
  </br>
        <?php 
  if ( is_user_logged_in() ) { $user = get_current_user_id(); }
  $votantes = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'votantes', false); if (in_array($user, $votantes)) {} else {echo 
  '<input type="radio" id="star5" name="rating5" value="' .$rating5. '" /><label for="star5" title="Muy Bueno">5 stars</label>
   <input type="radio" id="star4" name="rating4" value="' .$rating4. '" /><label for="star4" title="Bueno">4 stars</label>
   <input type="radio" id="star3" name="rating3" value="' .$rating3. '" /><label for="star3" title="Regular">3 stars</label>
   <input type="radio" id="star2" name="rating2" value="' .$rating2. '" /><label for="star2" title="Malo">2 stars</label>
   <input type="radio" id="star1" name="rating1" value="' .$rating1. '" /><label for="star1" title="Muy Malo">1 star</label>';} ?>  
  </div>
  </br>
  </br>
  Número de Votaciones: <?php echo $votaciones; ?>
  </br>
  <?php  if ($votantes1 == "") {echo 'null';} else {echo $votantes1;} ?>
  </br>
  <?php  echo $user; ?>
  </br>
  <?php  if (in_array($user, $votantes)) { echo 'el usuario si está'; } else {echo 'el usuario no está';}  ?>
  
  <p>Promedio de Puntuación: <?php echo $promedio; ?></p>
  <p>Dividendo: <?php echo $dividendo; ?></p>
  
    </div>
     <?php
}

$votantes = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'votantes', false);  
  
add_action( 'save_post', 'votacion_critica_metabox_save' );
function votacion_critica_metabox_save( $post_id )
{
    // Bail if we're doing an auto save
    if( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) return;

    // if Nonce isn't there, or we can't verify it, bail
    if( !isset( $_POST['mi_critica_nonce'] ) || !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['mi_critica_nonce'], 'critica_nonce' ) ) return;

    // if Current user can't edit this post, bail
    if( !current_user_can( 'edit_post' ) ) return;

    // Save the data
 
    // Review data before saving
  if ( is_user_logged_in() ) { echo $user = get_current_user_id(); }
 if (isset( $_POST['rating5'] ) OR isset( $_POST['rating4'] ) OR isset( $_POST['rating3'] ) OR isset( $_POST['rating2'] ) OR isset( $_POST['rating1'] )) {add_post_meta( $post_id, 'votantes', $user);}
 if( empty( $_POST['rating5'] )) {add_post_meta( $post_id, 'rating5', 0, true );} 
 if (isset( $_POST['rating5'] )) {update_post_meta( $post_id, 'rating5', $rating5 = $_POST['rating5'] + 1 );}
 if( empty( $_POST['rating4'] )) {add_post_meta( $post_id, 'rating4', 0, true );} 
 if (isset( $_POST['rating4'] )) {update_post_meta( $post_id, 'rating4', $rating4 = $_POST['rating4'] + 1 );}
 if( empty( $_POST['rating3'] )) {add_post_meta( $post_id, 'rating3', 0, true );} 
 if (isset( $_POST['rating3'] )) {update_post_meta( $post_id, 'rating3', $rating3 = $_POST['rating3'] + 1 );}
 if( empty( $_POST['rating2'] )) {add_post_meta( $post_id, 'rating2', 0, true );} 
 if (isset( $_POST['rating2'] )) {update_post_meta( $post_id, 'rating2', $rating2 = $_POST['rating2'] + 1 );}
 if( empty( $_POST['rating1'] )) {add_post_meta( $post_id, 'rating1', 0, true );} 
 if (isset( $_POST['rating1'] )) {update_post_meta( $post_id, 'rating1', $rating1 = $_POST['rating1'] + 1 );}
 
 }
```

```html
// Agregar metabox Para votaciones de critica

add_action( 'add_meta_boxes_post', 'votacion_critica_metabox' );
function votacion_critica_metabox()
{
 add_meta_box( 'metabox-critica-votacion', 'Votacion para Criticas', 'votacion_critica_metabox_callback', 'post', 'normal', 'high' );
}

function votacion_critica_metabox_callback( $post )
 
{
 $post_id = $post->ID;
 $values = get_post_meta( $post->ID );
 $rating5 = get_post_meta( $post->ID,'rating5', true );
 $rating4 = get_post_meta( $post->ID,'rating4', true );
 $rating3 = get_post_meta( $post->ID,'rating3', true );
 $rating2 = get_post_meta( $post->ID,'rating2', true );
 $rating1 = get_post_meta( $post->ID,'rating1', true );
 $votaciones = $rating1 + $rating2 + $rating3 + $rating4 + $rating5;
 $dividendo = (1 * $rating1) + (2 * $rating2) + (3 * $rating3) + (4 * $rating4) + (5 * $rating5);
 $promedio = $dividendo/$votaciones;
 $votantes1 = get_post_meta( $post->ID,'votantes', true );
 
    wp_nonce_field( 'critica_nonce', 'mi_critica_nonce' );
    ?>
  <br><input type="hidden" name="votantes" id="my_meta_box_prueba" size="30" placeholder="votantes" value="<?php echo $votantes1; ?>" />
  
  </br>
  <input type="hidden" id="promedio" name="promedio" value="1" />
  <div class="rating">
  <div class="cover" ></div>
  <input type="radio" id="star5" name="resultado5"  <?php if ( $promedio == 5 ) {echo 'checked';} ?> /><label for="star5" title="Muy bueno">5 stars</label>
  
  <input type="radio" id="star4" name="resultado4"  <?php if ( $promedio >= 4 && $promedio < 5 ) {echo 'checked';} ?> /><label for="star4" title="Bueno">4 stars</label>
  
  <input type="radio" id="star3" name="resultado3"  <?php if ( $promedio >= 3 && $promedio < 4 ) {echo 'checked';} ?> /><label for="star3" title="Regular">3 stars</label>
  
  <input type="radio" id="star2" name="resultado2"  <?php if ( $promedio >= 2 && $promedio < 3 ) {echo 'checked';} ?> /><label for="star2" title="Malo">2 stars</label>
  
  <input type="radio" id="star1" name="resultado1"  <?php if ( $promedio >= 1 && $promedio < 2 ) {echo 'checked';} ?> /><label for="star1" title="Muy Malo">1 star</label>
  
  </br>
        <?php 
  if ( is_user_logged_in() ) { $user = get_current_user_id(); }
  $votantes = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'votantes', false); if (in_array($user, $votantes)) {} else {echo 
  '<input type="radio" id="star5" name="rating5" value="' .$rating5. '" /><label for="star5" title="Muy Bueno">5 stars</label>
   <input type="radio" id="star4" name="rating4" value="' .$rating4. '" /><label for="star4" title="Bueno">4 stars</label>
   <input type="radio" id="star3" name="rating3" value="' .$rating3. '" /><label for="star3" title="Regular">3 stars</label>
   <input type="radio" id="star2" name="rating2" value="' .$rating2. '" /><label for="star2" title="Malo">2 stars</label>
   <input type="radio" id="star1" name="rating1" value="' .$rating1. '" /><label for="star1" title="Muy Malo">1 star</label>';} ?>  
  </div>
  </br>
  </br>
  Número de Votaciones: <?php echo $votaciones; ?>
  </br>
  <?php  if ($votantes1 == "") {echo 'null';} else {echo $votantes1;} ?>
  </br>
  <?php  echo $user; ?>
  </br>
  <?php  if (in_array($user, $votantes)) { echo 'el usuario si está'; } else {echo 'el usuario no está';}  ?>
  
  <p>Promedio de Puntuación: <?php echo $promedio; ?></p>
  <p>Dividendo: <?php echo $dividendo; ?></p>
  
    </div>
     <?php
}

$votantes = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'votantes', false);  
  
add_action( 'save_post', 'votacion_critica_metabox_save' );
function votacion_critica_metabox_save( $post_id )
{
    // Bail if we're doing an auto save
    if( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) return;

    // if Nonce isn't there, or we can't verify it, bail
    if( !isset( $_POST['mi_critica_nonce'] ) || !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['mi_critica_nonce'], 'critica_nonce' ) ) return;

    // if Current user can't edit this post, bail
    if( !current_user_can( 'edit_post' ) ) return;

    // Save the data
 
    // Review data before saving
  if ( is_user_logged_in() ) { echo $user = get_current_user_id(); }
 if (isset( $_POST['rating5'] ) OR isset( $_POST['rating4'] ) OR isset( $_POST['rating3'] ) OR isset( $_POST['rating2'] ) OR isset( $_POST['rating1'] )) {add_post_meta( $post_id, 'votantes', $user);}
 if( empty( $_POST['rating5'] )) {add_post_meta( $post_id, 'rating5', 0, true );} 
 if (isset( $_POST['rating5'] )) {update_post_meta( $post_id, 'rating5', $rating5 = $_POST['rating5'] + 1 );}
 if( empty( $_POST['rating4'] )) {add_post_meta( $post_id, 'rating4', 0, true );} 
 if (isset( $_POST['rating4'] )) {update_post_meta( $post_id, 'rating4', $rating4 = $_POST['rating4'] + 1 );}
 if( empty( $_POST['rating3'] )) {add_post_meta( $post_id, 'rating3', 0, true );} 
 if (isset( $_POST['rating3'] )) {update_post_meta( $post_id, 'rating3', $rating3 = $_POST['rating3'] + 1 );}
 if( empty( $_POST['rating2'] )) {add_post_meta( $post_id, 'rating2', 0, true );} 
 if (isset( $_POST['rating2'] )) {update_post_meta( $post_id, 'rating2', $rating2 = $_POST['rating2'] + 1 );}
 if( empty( $_POST['rating1'] )) {add_post_meta( $post_id, 'rating1', 0, true );} 
 if (isset( $_POST['rating1'] )) {update_post_meta( $post_id, 'rating1', $rating1 = $_POST['rating1'] + 1 );}
 
 }
```